# Атрибуты виджетов

Tags: python

Как узнать все атрибуты, которые есть у виджета?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще как вариант установить IPython, у него по двойному табу показываются все атрибуты.

Answer (score 1):

Если под виджетом имеется ввиду модуль, то:

```
import module_name
help(module_name)
```

Comment: Нет. Допустим мы создали виджет Техт... Мне нужны все его атрибуты. Есть функция, которая возвращает подобную инфу. Забыл, какая :)))))

Comment: dir(Text) вернет все функции объекта.  
Или речь идёт о полях?

Comment: А что, поля по dir() не отображаются? Изначально в питоне и методы (функции?) суть поля.

Comment: Ну так то-же самое `help(Text)`, выведет список всех заданных атрибутов в читабельном виде с описанием (если есть).

Comment: виджет.configurе()
Всем спасибо!